# exception: The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke! targetService is SecurityDepositServiceImpl

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I am new to web-service and I have created one web service in my existing project using eclipse 'Bottom Up java Bean service', server is Tomcat 6, Spring Framework 2.5, and not using Maven and Ant. In my project eclipse automatically included all required jars in lib but when I try to invoke getName() from browser it gives error like:
exception: The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke! targetService is SecurityDepositServiceImpl 
So please suggest me what should I do to run my service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have recieved this error in the past.  You will get this error if it *cannot find the service name in the URL*.  Keep in mind the URL is also case-sensative.  You should be able to hit the URL in the browser and recieve a message like so:

> **YourWebServiceName**
>   Hi there, this is an AXIS service!
>   *Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...*

I also fixed this issue before when there was a trailing slash "YourService/" in the URL!  Watch out for that one too!  Took me FOREVER to find it.

Comment: Oh man, I cannot begin to describe how much time you just saved me.  Thanks, pixelbobby.

Comment: The trailing slash was destroying my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you suddenly see this error in a project that used to compile and run, this is what helped me:

In my case, it was a maven build, the application (an Atlassian plugin) was normally run from under IntelliJ idea. My guess is that there was not enough free disk space, and some build artifact was truncated, but maven could not tell a part from the whole. I had to delete `.m2/repository` and `target/`, and run `atlas-unit-test.bat` and `atlas-run.bat` from the command line just to download the dependencies (this does not work from IntelliJ Idea, no idea why).

Answer (score 0):

Sample ant file for build a webService project where deployment descriptor web.xml will route all Services

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="dist/MyProjectWebService.war"
        webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="WebContent" />
        <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <classes dir="build/classes" />
    </war>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="dist" />
    <delete dir="build" />
</target>
```