# Java - Exposing a DAO Class that implements an interface as a Web Service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, axis, dao

I have this project where I want to expose a DAO Class as a web service. Unfortunately it seems that a class that *implements an interface* (or extends an abstract class) can't be exposed.
The requirements are **Axis 1.4**, **Tomcat 7** - And I am using the IDE **Eclipse**.

Here's a bit of the interface `IDAO.java`

```
public interface IDAO<T> {

    public final static Connection connect = SQLiteJDBC.getInstance();

    public T find(long id);

    public Product[] findByName(String search);
}
```

Then some code from `ProductDAO.Java` (*This is the class that is being exposed as a web service*)

```
public class ProductDAO implements IDAO<Product> {
    @Override
    public Product find(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // DB Query 
        return prod;
    }

    @Override   
    public Product[] findByName(String search) {
        // Database action
        // Retourne l'arraylist converti en array   
        return prods;
    }

}
```

Then I use Eclipse built-in Bottom-up wizard to generate the web service.

But when I try the exposed methods in the browser or the eclipse web service explorer, I get this error.

`The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke! targetService is ProductDAO`

I tried to convert the `IDAO` to an abstract class. But the generation process won't go through.
Anyone have had similar situation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: verify that URLMapper are not missing...

Comment: Sorry guys, though I know Java - Web services are new to me. Being a learning project, feel free to suggest better design, better way to do stuff...

Answer (score 3):

2 points in this answer:

1) Take a look to this question: [exception: The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke! targetService is SecurityDepositServiceImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650326/exception-the-axis-engine-could-not-find-a-target-service-to-invoke-targetserv)

It seems that Axis expect to find the service name in the URL, watch carefully to type the URL being case-sensitive to the service name, and watch out for the possible trailing slash as pointed in the linked answer.

2) There is a philosophical question in DAO pattern: you use DAO pattern when your application access to an external source of data, and that can be everything: configuration files, Databases, external services...
But this statement is wrong:

> "I want to expose a DAO Class as a web service"

That's not the correct way to use DAO: you don't expose a DAO, **you use DAO interface to access to external data**.

Anyway, if your application is ***client*** of an external web service, then that is the correct situation to use DAO pattern to provide an interface that allow your business object to access to that source of data (that web service).

I suggest you a very interesting reading about DAO in Oracle docs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

EDIT:

To clarify this is an example of the Java Axis service I'm expecting

```
public class ProductService {
  public int create(String name) {
    return new ProductDAO().add(name);
  }

  public List<Product> read() {
    return new ProductDAO().getAll();
  }

  //... and so on for the CRUD operations
}
```

I don't know how to expand the answer anymore, just keep in mind:

- your DAO access to the source of data (in this case your Database).
- the web service expose a method.
- DAO is one thing, web service is another thing.
- You can clearly call your DAO in your web method.

Comment: I've seen the other question you linked to, but it did not solve my issue. 
Actually, this is the server side: my DAO works (CRUD) with data from a database and pass it to the application layer.
Now that I want to expose this, I thought I could directly expose the DAO class since the webservice will be doing the same CRUD operations...

Comment: But that's a design error: You correctly use your DAO to get Data from DB, but it's wrong to bind it to your WS interface!
As a matter of fact your WS interface is **NOT** a DAO interface. So just call the DAO CRUD operation in the method you're going to expose.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But can you be more explicit? on this `As a matter of fact your WS interface is NOT a DAO interface`. My problem is that I can't call the ProductDAO methods from WS client I get the error `The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke! targetService is ProductDAO`

Comment: If your application is the client, then you'll have the DAO of your WS client that maybe *looks like* the DAO of your WS Server, but they are not the same thing: the 1st one deals with your Web Service, and the 2nd (ProductDAO) deals with Database. I repeat, exposing directly DAO methods as a service is a bad design, because you are strictly binding 2 things that are supposed to be separated (DAO to access DB, and your WS methods).

Comment: So if I follow, you are suggesting to add another layer between the DAO and the Web Services. Am I right?
Can you suggest a way to go?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting to add a layer between them, but I suggest to keeep them separated. I don't know your application, so I can just provide you a pseudo example in the answer to explain what I'm trying to say. I can't do anything more..